# Game Object, components priority?

Tags: c++

So, my first attempt to create a component based game object is this:

```
class GameObject;

class GameObjectComponent
{
public:
    virtual ~GameObjectComponent();
    virtual void Update(GameObject* obj, const sf::Time& deltaTime) = 0;
};

class GameObject
{
public:
    GameObject();
    virtual ~GameObject();

    virtual void Update(const sf::Time& deltaTime);
    virtual void AddComponent(
      std::unique_ptr<GameObjectComponent> component, 
      std::string componentName);
    virtual GameObjectComponent* GetComponent(std::string componentName);

    float GetVelocity();
    float AddVelocity(float velocity);
    void SetVelocity(float velocity);
    sf::Vector2f GetPosition();
    sf::Vector2f MovePosition(sf::Vector2f movement);
    void SetPosition(sf::Vector2f position);

private:
    float mVelocity;
    sf::Vector2f mPosition;
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<GameObjectComponent>> mComponents;
};
```

**The cpp**

```
#include "GameObject.h"

namespace Engine{
GameObjectComponent::~GameObjectComponent()
{
}

GameObject::GameObject()
{
    mVelocity = 0.f;
    mPosition = sf::Vector2f(0.f,0.f);
}


GameObject::~GameObject()
{
}

void GameObject::Update(const sf::Time& deltaTime)
{
    for (
      auto iterator = mComponents.begin(); 
      iterator != mComponents.end();
      ++iterator)
    {
        iterator->second->Update(this, deltaTime);
    }
}

void GameObject::AddComponent(
  std::unique_ptr<GameObjectComponent> component, 
  std::string componentName)
{
    mComponents[componentName] = std::move(component);
}

GameObjectComponent* GameObject::GetComponent(std::string componentName)
{
    return mComponents[componentName].get();
}

float GameObject::GetVelocity()
{
    return mVelocity;
}
float GameObject::AddVelocity(float velocity)
{
    mVelocity += velocity;
    return mVelocity;
}
void GameObject::SetVelocity(float velocity)
{
    mVelocity = velocity;
}
sf::Vector2f GameObject::GetPosition()
{
    return mPosition;
}
sf::Vector2f GameObject::MovePosition(sf::Vector2f movement)
{
    mPosition += movement;
    return mPosition;
}
void GameObject::SetPosition(sf::Vector2f position)
{
    mPosition = position;
}
}
```

and it works, but now I'm worried about priority.

Let's say I have these components: Movement, Phyisic, Renderer, NetworkSync
then they should run in order, otherwise the player could be rendered in the wrong spot, make a movement they should be able to do, or don't sync correctly with other players.

I'm not sure how to handle this without tanking the performance, and without losing too much flexibility.

Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: You could control it explicitly by having AddComponent put each component in a std::vector. Iterate over that for update. (You could keep the std::map also, if you need to look up by name a lot.)

Answer (score 1):

One way you could achieve what you need is to add a "priority" attribute to your GameObjectComponent; then add a mComponentsInOrder vector to your GameOjbect and keep ordered references in order, and sort it when you add new components.

```
class GameObjectComponent
{
public:

    virtual ~GameObjectComponent();
    virtual void Update(GameObject* obj, const sf::Time& deltaTime) = 0;
    static bool sortOnPriority(
      const GameObjectComponent& a1, 
      const GameObjectComponent& a2)
    {
      return a1->mPriority > a2-mPriority;
    }
private:
    std::string mComponentName;
    int         mPriority;
};


class GameObject
{
private:
  std::vector<GameObjectComponent*> mComponentsInExecOrder;
}

void GameObject::AddComponent(
  std::unique_ptr<GameObjectComponent> component, 
  std::string componentName)
{
    mComponents[componentName] = std::move(component);
    mComponentsInExecOrder.push_back(component.get());
    std::sort(
      mComponentsInExecOrder.begin(), 
      mComponentsInExecOrder.end(), 
      GameObjectComponent::sortOnPriority);
}


void GameObject::Update(const sf::Time& deltaTime)
{
    for ( auto item : mComponentsInExecOrder )
    {
      item->Update(this, deltaTime);
    }
}
```

The vector does not own the components, so you have to manage it when you add and remove components to/from your game object, but they're in the proper order when you update the gameobject.

I haven't tested this exact code so I'm not sure this works out of the box (the sort infrastructure), so it might need to be refined.

Also, if all your components have a name, why isn't the name *inside* your component object instead of having to carry it around like you seem to be doing?

One more thing; you may have a design flaw: you seem to be using a sort of ECS; now I wonder why your "physics" (velocity/movement/position) properties are set on the GameObject itself and not within components. Is your graphics component required to know about the velocity?

A last observation, you might want to try and pass your strings by const-by-ref instead of plainly copying them around like your code is currently doing it; you might get a bit of speed in there!

**P.S.**

Something you should be aware of (from [www.cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/)):

> `unordered_map` containers are faster than `map` containers to access individual elements by their key, **although they are generally less efficient for range iteration** through a subset of their elements.

Comment: Thank you! I will try it like that. the position/velocity is outside so it can be accessed more easily from different components, I could've probably avoided the velocity, but the position will be shared a lot.